# How do I uninstall MySQL?

Tags: mysql, software-uninstall

I installed MySQL using `sudo apt-get`. Now I need to remove it from my system.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 421, accepted):

I assume that you don't need MySQL anymore and you have already taken backup of your important databases. I suggest you to take backup of your important MySQL databases.

Note: Your all mysql data will be lost.

First make sure that MySQL service is stopped.

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

Remove MySQL related all packages completely.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
```

Remove MySQL configuration and data. If you have changed database location in your MySQL configuration, you need to replace `/var/lib/mysql` according to it.

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

(Optional) Remove unnecessary packages.

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

(Optional) Remove apt cache.

```
sudo apt autoclean
```

Comment: I guess this doesn't work. After I do these steps, I tried : `sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5`. But it shows : `mysql-client-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.`. Is that mean still mysql resides in my pc?

Comment: If I try `sudo dpkg --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common` I get : `dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching mysql-server
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching mysql-client
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching mysql-common
`. I'm bit confused now. Is that `mysql` have been removed or not?

Comment: Why does this remove `xbmc` and `xbmc-bin` as well? There are no `xbmc` tables in `mysql` when browsing with `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: this wasn't sufficient for me, a few more things had to be done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16178696/447661

Comment: I tried all the commands listed here and afterwards if I type 'mysql' into the terminal and press tab twice I still see some option come up for mysql, does this mean anything? > mysql mysqld mysql_upgrade mysqlcheck mysql_install_db

Comment: The config files have remained though, in /etc/mysql. Should those be manually deleted?

Comment: This also wasn't sufficient for me - for me, also, the answer here instead worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16178696/368896

Comment: You might want to add: `rm -rf /var/log/mysql`

Comment: Run this as well to be absolutely sure that you removed everything `sudo apt-get purge mysql* mariadb*`

Comment: For whoever this does not work - try removing them one after one, in various orders.

Comment: `sudo rm -rf  /var/lib/mysql` will remove your databases in default location. DO a back up first, if you feel you may need your data later on!

Comment: i tried this and boom everything along with mysql gets removed. i will not recommend this solution

Comment: be careful on using `sudo apt autoremove`. It deleted a lot of important stuff from my server!

Answer (score 120):

all the above solutions are correct but I would try with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

This will uninstall all mysql related packages.

Comment: This is the easiest/simplest way to get rid of everything mysql-related. Though the wildcard here will match pretty much any package with 'mysq' in it's name, so you might want to specify `sudo apt-get remove --purge -s 'mysql*'` to be more specific.

Comment: Seconded on the use of a more specific regex.  I ended up using the regex of '^mysql-*'  Initially, I was going to run mysql*, but found out it caught a ton of stuff unrelated...like:Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite' for regex '^mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for regex '^mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core' for regex '^mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysqmail' for regex '^mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysqmail-pure-ftpd-logger' for regex '^mysql*'

Comment: I tried all the commands listed here and afterwards if I type 'mysql' into the terminal and press tab twice I still see some option come up for mysql, does this mean anything? > mysql mysqld mysql_upgrade mysqlcheck mysql_install_db

Comment: This only worked for me when I used sudo apt-get -f autoremove

Comment: this gives me a couple of errors like ` E: Unable to locate package mysql
`. my installation seems to be a bit messed up. and it kind of frightening that i cant even re-install it.

Comment: this is dangerous. use the `*` at your own peril. `bash` will expand all matching cases and remove them, even if they might be unrelated to `mysql`.

Comment: it did not remove the files in /etc/mysql for my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: PLEASE DONT USE THIS!!! This removed atom, git, perl and lots of other important packages from my system. Dont know why

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` very misleading... it also uninstall some of installed applications

Comment: @Roel that would only happened if your application is depended on any of mentioned packages you remove.

Answer (score 34):

This will remove mysql 5.6 from ubuntu 15.04

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Comment: Manually removing the directories seemed necessary for me (so +1), perhaps because my directories were symbolic links?

Comment: I felt like your anwser was the most concise,  so I wantedo comment here.  I did something similar for mariadb, however i noticed I had a dangling system service. I had to remove it using: http://superuser.com/a/936976/260852

Comment: Thanks, this also works for mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 10):

First you need to stop your mysql server from service.

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Then You can use purge command to uninstall

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client
```

**Note:** the above based on your package list. I have installed both server and client. This will for your convineient

Comment: Stopping the MySQL service was key for me. I had it running and kept getting an error: `dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: fork failed: Cannot allocate memory E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)`  
  
Stopping MySQL, then running   
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`   
followed by  
`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`  
worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

## Completly uninstall mysql:

```
sudo -i
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
apt-get --yes purge mysql*
apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
deluser --remove-home mysql
delgroup mysql
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld ~/.mysql_history
updatedb
```

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/640900/588848) answer and many others...

Answer (score 5):

I don't use Ubuntu much but what I think you should try is what I did.

I first typed this in command line : `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common`,

then followed with this below : `sudo apt-get autoremove`

and finally typed this : `sudo apt-get autoclean`.

I found that it was removed.

Answer (score 4):

I forgot the MySQL root password and needed to reset.
I tried [this](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password), but it didn't work, because it kept saying "can't write logs" or something similar.

My solution was to completely remove MySQL from Ubuntu 13.10 and fresh installation.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

I had to run the last command because Ubuntu sometimes keeps some libs even you try to purge them all.

Now, I use this command to install MySQL server and client:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, It will fully wipeout out every single file of MySQL from your system:

```
sudo service mysql stop  #or mysqld
sudo killall -9 mysql
sudo killall -9 mysqld
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo deluser -f mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.7
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.7
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

When I tried `sudo apt-get purge mysql*` it didn't work.

Purged *mysql5* with:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-*
```

Then for cleaning up:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```