# Not able to uninstall MySQL with apt-get

Tags: apt, 14.04, mysql

I had downloaded the generic Linux 64 bit MySQL 5.6.17 TAR archive from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and installed on my 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04, following the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-installation.html.

I am having some problems with the server, so i want to uninstall and do a fresh installation. But if i try the usual `apt-get remove mysql-server`(as per [How do I uninstall Mysql?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql)), i get :

```
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
```

I am guessing this is because i did not use apt-get to install in the first place. I had used `scripts/mysql_install_db` as per the instructions.

So is there some other way to uninstall MySQL server or is it ok to just delete the installation folder?

**Edit**

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep "mysql"
```

gives the below result :

```
libdbd-mysql-perl               install
libmysqlclient18:amd64          install
mysql-client                    install
mysql-client-5.5                install
mysql-client-core-5.5           install
mysql-common                    install
mysql-workbench-community       install
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not too sure whether this will help but can you please try, `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep "mysql"` and post the output if you see any packages or matches. This command will output packages relating to the word **mysql** while printing all the installed packages. :)

Comment: I have updated the question with the output

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove mysql*`

Comment: **AvinashRaj** Exactly the same command that I was trying to comment on. @faizal please look into my answer

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you need to completely remove **mysql** related packages and its configs, please try below;

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*     # will remove all relating packages and its config
sudo apt-get autoremove               
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

And above command will completely remove all **mysql** related packages.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks AzkerM. But i am really nervous about doing this now. I have managed to make the existing MySQL work for now after a lot of experimenting. If i do face more problems, i will surely give this a try.

Comment: It is always a best practice to make a use of official repo's available within **Ubuntu** unless you've no other choice. Anyhow, its your call & in any event we're always happy to help. :)

Comment: I did not use the Ubuntu repo because it was downloading MySQL 5.5, while 5.6 was available for download from the mysql site. I have realized now that was an error of judgement :(

Comment: Well there is a [**PPA for MySQL 5.6**](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/mysql-5.6) given with an explanation on Launchpad which you should have tried. I also see certain [bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1312936) reported relating to this. Anyhow, there is no victory without pain. If your package is working and issues sorted, good to go though.

Comment: A little side note is that I had to go to / to execute the remove --purge command. Standing in my home directory resulted in apt-get not being able to locate packages

Answer (score 3):

If you installed MYSql from .tar.gz file, you can't able to uninstall it through Ubuntu's native package management system (`apt-get`).

Find the `uninstall.sh` script inside the extracted directory and run it to completely remove all the files related to MYSQL.

Comment: Does such a script exist? I could not find it in my installation folder(find $MYSQL_HOME -name 'uninstall.sh')

Comment: Most of the .tar.gz files comes with an un-installation script. I don't know about MYSQL.

Comment: you right. The script is `/root/oneinstack/uninstall.sh` on my server.

Answer (score 1):

The following will uninstall everything that contain `mysql`.

```
apt-get remove --purge mysql*.*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
```

Then run again the following to check any remaining packages.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep "mysql"
```

In my case, I only see `mysql-common`.

Reinstall and everything should work.

Comment: Superb. Works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked, without putting myself at risk of removing core MySQL services.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-workbench*
```