# How do I uninstall MySQL completely?

Tags: mysql, uninstall

The answers to related questions forget to:

- remove the MySQL databases
- remove the `mysql` user
- remove the logs in `/var/log`

How do I uninstall MySQL completely?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Building off of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16178696/463897), open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run the following:

```bash
sudo -i
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
deluser --remove-home mysql
delgroup mysql
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
updatedb
exit
```

If you want to delete the log of what you did while using the `mysql` client:

```bash
rm ~/.mysql_history
```

If you want to delete the logs of what *all users on the system* did while using the `mysql` client (the other users might be unhappy with this):

```bash
awk -F : '{ print($6 "/.mysql_history"); }' /etc/passwd | xargs -r -d '\n' -- sudo rm -f --
```

or for all logs including those outside of existing user home directories:

```bash
sudo find / -name .mysql_history -delete
```

Comment: You may also need `dpkg -l | grep mysql` to list any installed mysql packages, then e.g. `sudo apt-get purge mysql-common` for each entry

Comment: If you re-install mysql afterwards, you may have to run `mkdir /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql` and  `mkdir /etc/mysql/conf.d/` again.

Comment: What about /var/lib/mysql/mysql-files and /var/lib/mysql-keyring ?

Comment: This is very, very risky stuff! Please do only if you're absolutely certain, that you don't need any data from the your mysql anymore. (check additionally `ls -la /var/lib/mysql`)

Comment: This completely botched my system...

Comment: Be careful in WSL something is missing now or something, so any subsequent install or OS upgrade fails. Still trying to figure it out, I don't want to start fresh with WSL. No useful error aside from pointing to mysql server and E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 37):

I found some help, but it did not remove everything. I added an asterisk before and after mysql like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge *mysql\*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: Are you trying to answer the question ?

Comment: I would also `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql` If I didn't do that, I ran into trouble when re-provisioning the server (using geerlingguy's ansible-role-mysql).

Comment: It also removes php mysqli extension

Comment: CAUTION: this may remove a bunch of other packages that any link to MySQL, read carefully what will be removed.

Comment: This does not remove any of the three things the OP asked how to remove in the question.  It does not remove the databases, it doesn't remove the logs, and it doesn't remove the mysql user.

Answer (score 1):

I used a collab of 2 answers, first I ran this

- sudo -i
- service mysql stop
- killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
  apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
- apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
- apt-get autoclean
- deluser --remove-home mysql
- delgroup mysql
- rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql
  /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
  /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
- updatedb
- exit

Then checked, but still had an error, so as backup, I ran this within the terminal.

- sudo apt-get remove --purge *mysql*
- sudo apt-get autoremove
- sudo apt-get autoclean

Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, that worked for me, was to use Synamptic Package Manager. On the left hand pane,where it says: *All, Installed, etc*. there is an entry for **Not Installed (residual config.)** (or similar wording). Under there I found options to clear all MySQL install files. This worked for MySQL 5.7.

Comment: This is identical to `apt purge <package>` and it does not remove any of the three things the OP asked how to remove.