# Error in installing mysql-server in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql

When I install mysql-server, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

However, I am able to install the mysql-client without any problem. I have tried all the solutions given for related questions but nothing worked.
The related problems I have tried are:

- [16.04 upgrade broke mysql-server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Error Installing mySql on
  Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766038/error-installing-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Install MySql 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762384/install-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04)

The following question also does not match with my problem: [Error in installing Mysql-server in ubuntu16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795105/error-in-installing-mysql-server-in-ubuntu16-04)

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check what other mysql packages you have in the system - `apt list --installed | grep mysql`. In my case there was a conflict with `mysql-common` and I had to remove it (it also removed some of the packages I need, so I reinstalled them later). After that I was able to install mysql normally.

Comment: Thanks Cherry, but there are no other mysql packages. The `apt list --installed | grep mysql` returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution from this [site](https://makandracards.com/makandra/39899-install-mysql-5-6-in-ubuntu-16-04).

As stated in other answers, uninstall all the existing mysql modules. To get the list of installed mysql modules, use the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

Download the `mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb` from the [MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/).

Install the package using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
```

Create a new file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql` with this content

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "repo.mysql.com"
Pin-Priority: 999
```

Run the following command to update the cache

```
sudo apt update
```

Run the following command to install MySQL

```
sudo apt install mysql-client mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev
```