# Unable to install MariaDB on CircleCI ? Problems with dpkg

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, mysql, mariadb

I use CircleCI for as continuous integration solution,
I am trying to install MariaDB 10.1.20.

And I run this command:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude install -y mariadb-server
```

But I get this error:

```
Setting up mariadb-server-5.5 (5.5.54-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...

Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld
   ...done.
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-5.5 (>= 5.5.54-1ubuntu0.14.04.1); however:
  Package mariadb-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ... Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ... No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. Errors were encountered while processing:  mariadb-server-5.5  mariadb-server E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) A package failed to install.  Trying to recover: Setting up mariadb-server-5.5 (5.5.54-1ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...  * Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld    ...done. dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-5.5 (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:  mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-5.5 (>=
5.5.54-1ubuntu0.14.04.1); however:   Package mariadb-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while processing:  mariadb-server-5.5  mariadb-server
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking into the error. It tells me that mariaDB is dependable from the mariadb-server-5.5 ? Is this correct ?

Comment: Try `dpkg --configure -a`. If there is a real dependency problem, the command will tell you.

Comment: ubuntu@box1533:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
ubuntu@box1533:~$

I have nothing. This means that I haven't got the dependency problem. Right ?

Comment: Before I can provide an answer, please let us know 1) Which version of CircleCI you are using, 1.0 or 2.0, and 2) if 1.0, which image are you using? Ubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Using CircleCI 1.0. Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it, but know I have different problem.

Firstly in order to solve it, you have to delete all of default mysql from your server using this [How do I uninstall MySQL completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-completely)

Then, from the links from MariaDB site just one works and it's Bulgarish. https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=hostag&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=trusty--ubuntu_trusty

I have come up to other problem. I don't know how to put this prompt window about setting root password away. Anyhow that's other problem then this.