# Problem in removing MySql from ubuntu

Tags: apt, mysql, uninstall, mariadb

I want to completely remove mysql from ubuntu and decided to follow some steps found in [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-completely) :

I executed the following commands in order:

```
sudo -i
service mysql stop
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
apt-get --yes purge mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get --yes autoremove --purge
apt-get autoclean
deluser --remove-home mysql
delgroup mysql
rm -rf /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql* /var/log/upstart/mysql.log* /var/run/mysqld
updatedb
exit
rm ~/.mysql_history
awk -F : '{ print($6 "/.mysql_history"); }' /etc/passwd | xargs -r -d '\n' -- sudo rm -f --
sudo find / -name .mysql_history -delete
```

Well I should have a little more attention with the commands, the problem is that now any install command or even the upgrade returns faults. Ex executing command :

```
# apt-get upgrade
```

It results in the following errors :

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Calculando atualização... Pronto
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 0 não atualizados.
7 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
Depois desta operação, 0 B adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Você quer continuar? [S/n] s
Configurando mysql-common (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: erro: o caminho /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback da alternativa não existe
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote mysql-common (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 2
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de mysql-client-5.7:
 mysql-client-5.7 depende de mysql-common (>= 5.5); porém:
  Pacote mysql-common não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote mysql-client-5.7 (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de mysql-server-5.7:
 mysql-server-5.7 depende de mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); porém:
  Pacote mysql-client-5.7 não está configurado ainda.
 mysql-server-5.7 depende de mysql-common (>= 5.6.22-1~); porém:
  Pacote mysql-common não está configurado ainda.
 mysql-server-5.7 depende de mysql-common (>= 5.5); porém:
  Pacote mysql-common não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de mariadb-common:
 mariadb-common depende de mysql-common (>= 5.6.2Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois a mensagem de erro indica que é um erro de seguimento de um erro anterior.
                                                                               Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois a mensagem de erro indica que é um erro de seguimento de um erro anterior.
                              Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois MaxReports já foi atingido
             Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois MaxReports já foi atingido
                                                                            Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois MaxReports já foi atingido
                                                           Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois MaxReports já foi atingido
                                          5); porém:
  Pacote mysql-common não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote mariadb-common (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de mysql-server:
 mysql-server depende de mysql-server-5.7; porém:
  Pacote mysql-server-5.7 não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote mysql-server (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de mysql-testsuite-5.7:
 mysql-testsuite-5.7 depende de mysql-client-5.7 (= 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); porém:
  Pacote mysql-client-5.7 não está configurado ainda.
 mysql-testsuite-5.7 depende de mysql-server-5.7 (= 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); porém:
  Pacote mysql-server-5.7 não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote mysql-testsuite-5.7 (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de mysql-testsuite:
 mysql-testsuite depende de mysql-testsuite-5.7; porém:
  Pacote mysql-testsuite-5.7 não está configurado ainda.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote mysql-testsuite (--configure):
 problemas de dependência - deixando desconfigurado
Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 mysql-common
 mysql-client-5.7
 mysql-server-5.7
 mariadb-common
 mysql-server
 mysql-testsuite-5.7
 mysql-testsuite
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone know the way to solve the problem?
I've tried a lot of things on the internet, but with no success.

Comment: Em inglês por favor, as regras do site.

Comment: Sorry, it's in English now.

Comment: I found the correct answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853004/removing-mysql-5-5-completely

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall MySQL?](/q/172514/175814)