# Unable to purge mysql -server

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, mysql, services, purge

I am new to ubuntu. I am trying to uninstall mysql-server, while i'm doing it the purging process gets stuck at the line `Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)` and later on errors back saying `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem`. Can someone help me with this? I am using ubuntu 14.04lts. I tried doing what the error tells `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but it also errors back saying `dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process`.

Comment: I think I've had a similar problem... please check: http://askubuntu.com/a/805962/462938

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` is locked by another process. Please remove it first by executing following steps.

```
service mysqld status 
ps aux | grep mysql
sudo service mysql stop
kill -9 mysql_pid
rm -rf /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

Then you can try to purge MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
```

Comment: This steps not solve this problem for me(( Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to stop the mysql service before purging it.

1. You can see running services with:

   ```
   sudo service --status-all
   ```
2. Then, you can stop the mysql service running

   ```
   sudo service mysql stop
   ```
3. The service is now stopped, try again

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
   ```

Once done, you can try to re-install the mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

While these steps should be enough, you can head to [Cannot reinstall mysql-server after its purge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763534/cannot-reinstall-mysql-server-after-its-purge) and follow the provided steps to clean all your mysql setup.

Comment: I did the same thing, it returned an error `Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1). Maybe something to do with `dpkg`.
`

Comment: It's also showing while purging, `debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
`

Comment: First try to reboot the machine and try again. If still not working, try to remove the lock on dpkg [dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219545/dpkg-error-dpkg-status-database-is-locked-by-another-process)

Comment: Still not working!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem earlier, just finally fixed it. These are the steps that worked for me.

```
mysqldump --lock-all-tables -u root -p --all-databases > dump.sql
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -r /etc/mysql
sudo rm -r /var/log/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql -u root -p < dump.sql
sudo service mysql restart
```

http://teachmelinux.com/2017/01/ubuntu-server-mysql-5-7-update-failure-fix/