# MySQL refuses to install (configure?) 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql

I tried to install pterodactyl.io. There were a few issues, so I wanted to revert back to my previous mysql setup.

I uninstalled everything, including mysql but now I cannot seem to re-install mysql.

```
 Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
     Renaming
 removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)

 Job for
 mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error
 code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
 details.
     invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed. ●
 mysql.service - MySQL Community Server    Loaded: loaded
 (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
 Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon
 2017-03-13 14:46:15 CET; 5ms ago   Process: 16341
 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited,
 status=0/SUCCESS)   Process: 16340 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 16336
 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited,
 status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 16340 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 Mar 13 14:46:15 ns3023991.ip-149-202-64.eu systemd[1]: Failed to start
 MySQL ... Mar 13 14:46:15 ns3023991.ip-149-202-64.eu systemd[1]:
 mysql.service: Unit en... Mar 13 14:46:15 ns3023991.ip-149-202-64.eu
 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed ... Hint: Some lines were
 ellipsized, use -l to show in full. dpkg: error processing package
 mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):  subprocess installed
 post-installation script returned error exit status 1 No apport report
 written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error
 from a previous failure.
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:  mysql-server depends on
 mysql-server-5.7; however:   Package mysql-server-5.7 is not
 configured yet.

 dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):  dependency
 problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered while

 processing:  mysql-server-5.7  mysql-server E: Sub-process
 /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: First thing is to try `dpkg --configure -a`. Second thing is `sudo apt install -f`. What happens?

Comment: Found my answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763534/cannot-reinstall-mysql-server-after-its-purge