# MySQL unmet dependicies

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, mysql, dependencies

I tried installing MySQL-Workbench and I get the following errors. How do I solve them?

```
isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for isaac: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease        

Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ sudo apt install mysql-workbench
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-workbench : Depends: libgdal.so.1-1.11.3
               Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ apt-cache policy libgdal1i libgdal.so.1-1.11.3

libgdal1i: 
    Installed: (none) 
    Candidate: 1.11.3+dfsg-3build2 
    Version table: 1.11.3+dfsg-3build2 
    500 500 http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages 

libgdal.so.1-1.11.3: 
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: (none)
    Version table: –
```

Comment: Please update your question with output of `apt-cache policy libgdal1i libgdal.so.1-1.11.3`. On my xenial it installs normally (just `--simulate`d it). You have PPA or third-party repositories.

Comment: `isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ apt-cache policy libgdal1i libgdal.so.1-1.11.3libgdal1i:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.11.3+dfsg-3build2
  Version table:
     1.11.3+dfsg-3build2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
libgdal.so.1-1.11.3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
`

Comment: I suggest to switch to other mirror with Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`).

Comment: What mirror should I choose?

Comment: Start with *Main server*.

Comment: Alrighty, I will keep you updated.

Comment: Tried Main Server, the installation of the MySQL-Workbench still does not work.

Comment: Please update your question with output of the following command `grep -v ^# -r /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep deb`.

Comment: Part 1:
`isaac@isaac-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ grep -v ^# -r /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep deb
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse main universe restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/hanipouspilot-ubuntu-rtlwifi-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu xenial main
`

Comment: Part 2:
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-python-3_6-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/umang-ubuntu-indicator-stickynotes-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-y-ppa-manager-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial main
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is the following (please follow the steps accordingly):

1) [How do I uninstall MySQL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql)

2) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-1-%E2%80%94-installing-mysql

3) https://linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/install-and-configure-mysql-workbench-on-ubuntu/

So, what I should have initially done is configure the mysql server and only then install the mysql workbench.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have wrong contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

1.Please replace your lines with Gedit - `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse main universe restricted 
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
```

with these correct lines:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted multiverse universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted multiverse
```

2.save resulting `/etc/apt/sources.list`
3.run `sudo apt-get update`
4.install latest updates with `sudo apt-get upgrade`
5.install your software with `sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`

Comment: Hello N0rbert, thank you for your help! Question. When I want to save something in terminal, what do I press? Ctrl+S? Esc? Q?

Comment: Use `gedit` (see update above).

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much! I guess this post post should be stickied. Are you on LinkedIn?

Comment: Alright, now I have another question. I am trying to set up a connection, and I get the following error:

Connecting to MySQL server ...
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: You should use search here on just google to solve connection issues. It is another question.

Comment: Tried doing that, was not able to find a suitable solution. Looking for your guidance now.