# Completely reset mysql

Tags: apt, dpkg, mysql

I am having a lot of problems with mysql server. First, I couldn't log into the database, couldn't log in as root. When I ran `mysql_secure_installation`, it seemed to accept the password reset but still wouldn't log me in. I ran `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` and then manually reset the password, but this just prevented me from restarting mysql. the second time I couldn't even log in this way.

I've tried reconfiguring dpkg. I've *purged all mysql** packages. At some point, this process even broke the mysql-server package, and I couldn't reinstall mysql-server. However, the installation never prompted me to set a root password, and I thought it  normally did this.

Eventually, I got it installed again, somehow. But now MySQL won't start. I didn't have any schemas or tables I need in mysql, so I could just go scorched-earth in removing it.

There has to be a way for me to start over with a fresh mysql installation, set my password, and log in normally. However, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I see no release details, and it seems you've mostly just logged what happened without specifics (no  commands & messages, eg. it won't start without details on how started and/or any messages), and no clear question. It's better if we're not making assumptions...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I uninstall MySQL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql) and [How do I uninstall MySQL completely?](https://askubuntu.com/q/640899)

Comment: I received all kinds of errors along the way, but here are the ones I'm getting now;

`/etc/mysql/debian-start[5983]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is
Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql 
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck 
Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root' 
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add error messages. Formatting in comments make reading outputs difficult. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't able to, and now I can't edit my comment.

Comment: You need not to edit the comment. Instead [edit] the question.