# Mysql error "'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)'" and I can't reset root password either

Tags: server, mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm getting the following error for a couple of commands I'm trying to run AND I don't know the password whenever I'm prompted for that. (note: I just updated my ubuntu distribution to 22.04, but I previously didn't have a password set/had an empty password for 'root').

`error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)'`

It seems from most posts that the common issue is that mysql-server isn't actually running.
I can see that mine is running, though, with `sudo service mysql status` and the following commands return...

```
$ cat /etc/services | grep 3306
    mysql           3306/tcp
$  netstat -tulpn | grep 3306
    (No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

These commands are giving the "Can't connect..." error:

- mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
- mysqladmin version
- mysql
- mysql -u root
- mysql -u root -h localhost -p

Running `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p` seems to work in that it prompts me for a password, but none of my prior passwords are working and I have not been able to run `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` or `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &` successfully to reset the root password.

I have also run...

- sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade
- sudo apt install mysql-server
- sudo apt install mysql-client
- sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
- sudo dpkg --configure -a
- and followed the recommendations from the top two answers on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984956/cant-reset-root-password-with-skip-grant-tables-on-ubuntu-16
- and tried to uninstall MySQL by following directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172514/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql)
- and tried to back up the sock folder and restore it as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984956/cant-reset-root-password-with-skip-grant-tables-on-ubuntu-16)

Additional random info:

I also know that `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` did exist earlier in this process (I only have mysql.bak in that directory now), but when I run `sudo find / -type s`, it just returns a bunch of files/directories with "Permission Denied" (I assume because I'm in WSL), so I haven't checked that there could be another mysql.sock somewhere.

I also know that `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is just pointing to -> `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf`, which only has the following in it (other than some comments):

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Comment: Any progress?  Does `sudo mysql` get you to a prompt without the server?  If so, try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1133325/1165986) to reset the root password.

Comment: I finally got it to work. I removed mysql all over again and reinstalled. I was having trouble resetting the password for root, but I eventually got it. I think part of the issue may have been that I just didn't know that you have to use `sudo` when logging in as root...
@NotTheDr01ds

Comment: Cool - And yes, I believe (IIRC) that's because the *local* database file is owned by root.  So until the server is running, accessing/modifying the local file will require `sudo`.

Comment: you can try
`sudo chmod 777 -R /var/run/mysqld/`

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop MySQL (sudo systemctl stop mysql)
2. Verify process is stopped
3. Start MySQL with --skip-grant-tables

Alternativly purge mysql:
sudo apt purge mariadb-server mysql-common
Verify /etc/mysql and /var/lib/mysql are empty/ deleted

Reinstall

Comment: I can't run systemctl because I'm in WSL and I've done all of that already